Distinct Average Score by Group
I have a table like this:



ID (Auto)
Master_ID
Group_ID
Score




1
1
1
4


2
1
3
3.5


3
1
2
5


4
1
2
5


5
1
1
4



I am trying to get an average score for each Master_ID. Each Group_ID within a given Master_ID will always have the same score. For this reason I cannot do a straight average. I need to find a way to ignore the count of each Group_ID within a Master_ID. If I do a straight average, (because the scores of each Group_ID within a given Master_ID will always have the same score), the more occurrences of a Group_ID there are within a selected set, the more the score of that Group will influence the final average score. So basically I need the query to assume each Group_ID within a Master_ID appears once.
So basically I need to do distinct sum of score using Group_ID as the basis and divide that by a distinct count of Group_ID. In my example above this should be:
4 (for Group_ID 1) +
3.5 (for Group_ID 3) +
5 (for Group_ID 1) 2
= 12.5 / 3 (3 distinct groups exists) = 4.61
This is what I am currently trying to get working:
SELECT appraisal_lines_kbi.AppraisalID, cnt.oCount, sm.Scoring, ifnull(sm.Scoring/cnt.oCount, 0) AS AvrKbiScore 
FROM appraisal_lines_kbi 
left join (select AppraisalID, Scoring FROM appraisal_lines_kbi GROUP BY KbiGroup) sm 
ON appraisal_lines_kbi.AppraisalID = sm.AppraisalID
left join (Select AppraisalID, COUNT(DISTINCT(KbiGroup)) as oCount FROM appraisal_lines_kbi) cnt 
ON appraisal_lines_kbi.AppraisalID = cnt.AppraisalID
WHERE appraisal_lines_kbi.AppraisalID = 45


It seems simpler to first select distinct then aggregate for example
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT DISTINCT MASTER_ID,GROUP_ID,SCORE FROM T)
SELECT MASTER_ID,SUM(SCORE),COUNT(*),AVG(SCORE)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY MASTER_ID;

Assuming you are on version 8 or above..
https://dbfiddle.uk/_tj1kTUM

Thanks P.Salmon. I should have mentioned that I am using mysql 5.6. Any ideas for that?
